# Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK

Tags: asp.net, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have create an application using asp.net. It's live in server. I want to login my app through Facebook. That is if the user clicks the "Login with Facebook" he should be redirected to particular page. After that he should be redirected back to my app with data(user details). I have created an app in Facebook. I have search a lot in internet but, didn't get the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. 
Step 2.

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com
- On top header click on MY APPS > Add new App.
- Click on App Detail tab > fill all the information.
- Click on Status/Review tab > "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" change toggle button to "yes".
- Copy the clientID.This ID will use in facebook login development.
  For More Please Follow the Demo.Its working for me.[Facebook login demo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)
  Replace "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" with your APPID